# How can I reduce the redundancies of the fields handling of feed handler

Tags: scala, feed

I am subscript to a message feed for a number of fields, I need to set the values from the feed to the domain object and have code like below:

```
if (map.contains(quoteBidPriceAcronym)) {
  quote.bid.price = Some(map.get(quoteBidPriceAcronym).get.asInstanceOf[Number].doubleValue());
  quote.changed = true;
}
if (map.contains(quoteBidSizeAcronym)) {
  quote.bid.size = Some(sizeMultipler() * map.get(quoteBidSizeAcronym).get.asInstanceOf[Number].intValue());
  quote.changed = true;
}
if (map.contains(quoteBidNumAcronym)) {
  quote.bid.num = Some(map.get(quoteBidNumAcronym).get.asInstanceOf[Number].shortValue());
  quote.changed = true;
}
if (map.contains(quoteAskPriceAcronym)) {
  quote.ask.price = Some(map.get(quoteAskPriceAcronym).get.asInstanceOf[Number].doubleValue());
  quote.changed = true;
}
if (map.contains(quoteAskSizeAcronym)) {
  quote.ask.size = Some(sizeMultipler() * map.get(quoteAskSizeAcronym).get.asInstanceOf[Number].intValue());
  quote.changed = true;
}
if (map.contains(quoteAskNumAcronym)) {
  quote.ask.num = Some(map.get(quoteAskNumAcronym).get.asInstanceOf[Number].shortValue());
  quote.changed = true;
}
if (map.contains(quoteExchTimeAcronym)) {
  quote.exchtime = getExchTime(String.valueOf(map.get(quoteExchTimeAcronym).get));
}
```

It look pretty redundant, any suggestion to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
map.get(quoteBidPriceAcronym).map { item =>
    quote.bid.price = item.map(_.asInstanceOf[Number].doubleValue())
    quote.changed = true
}
```

Other issues might be better to fix outside. E.g. why map[quoteBidPriceAcronym] is storing an Option, if your code assumes it's not going to be None?

Comment: It can be None, isn't it? if the quoteBidPriceAcronym is not exist in the map

Comment: Yes, but the map entry itself does not have to be an Option, does it?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like code changing an object state (`quote`) but this is a question on Scala, not functional programming.

That said I would reverse the way you are using you map `map` keys. Instead of checking whether a value exists to perform some action, I'd have a map from your keys to actions and I'd iterate over your `map` elements.

e.g (assuming `map` is of the type `Map[String, Any]`):

```
val actions: Map[String, PartialFunction[Any, Unit]] = Map(
    (quoteBidPriceAcronym, {case n: Number =>  quote.bid.price = Some(n.doubleValue())}),
    (quoteBidSizeAcronym, {case n: Number =>  quote.bid.size = Some(sizeMultipler() * n.doubleValue())}),
    ...
    ...
)

for((k,v) <- map; action <- actions.get(k); _ <- action.lift(v))
    quote.changed = true;
```

The `for` construct here iterates over `map` key-values, then (next level of iteration, over the possible action available for the key. If an `action` is found, which is a partial function, it gets lifted to make it a function from `Any` to `Option[Unit]`. That way, you can iterate in an additional inner level so `quote.changed = true` is only run when the action is defined for `v`.

Comment: Thanks, it look cool but I wouldn't get it work, the domain object doesn't get updated

Comment: @carfield Could you post your `map` declaration?

Comment: It is just 
    var map = HashMap[String, Object]();

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
val handlers = Map[String, Number => Unit] (
   quoteBidPriceAcronym -> { n => quote.bid.price = Some(n.doubleValue) },
   quoteBidSizeAcronym -> { n => quote.bid.size = Some(sizeMultipler() * n.intValue }, 
etc. ...
)

for {
   (k,handler) <- handlers
   values <- map.get(k).toSeq
   quote.chanded = true
   _ = handler(n.asInstanceof[Number])
}
```

Comment: Not all of them are supposed to be instances of Number though.

Comment: Well, in this question, they all are ... 
If you need to handle different types, consider having different `handlers` maps for instance, or using PartialFunctions as another answer suggested ... although, at that point, I would really recommend seriously reconsidering your design.